# How to depend a POM with several modules in Maven

Tags: maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I have to include several libs into my project POM which are all sub-modules of `siddhi-extensions` as in this POM:

http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/wso2/siddhi/siddhi-extensions/3.0.3/siddhi-extensions-3.0.3.pom

Adding this dependency as below says:

```
Missing artifact org.wso2.siddhi:siddhi-extensions:jar:3.0.3.
```

```
<dependencies>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.siddhi</groupId>
        <artifactId>siddhi-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Using `dependencyManagement` will not include all sub-modules in a row:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.siddhi</groupId>
            <artifactId>siddhi-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>${siddhi.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Can I just simply import the `siddhi-extensions` to import all the sub-module libs in the `siddhi-extensions` project?

Answer (score 0):

[`org.wso2.siddhi:siddhi-extensions:3.0.3:pom`](http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/wso2/siddhi/siddhi-extensions/3.0.3/siddhi-extensions-3.0.3.pom) does not contain a `<dependencyManagement>`.

Though I couldn't find this in [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism, Importing Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) explicitely it seems that inherited `<dependencyManagement>` (from the parent [`org.wso2.siddhi:siddhi:3.0.3:pom`](http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/wso2/siddhi/siddhi/3.0.3/siddhi-3.0.3.pom)) isn't covered by `<scope>import`.

So, the `<dependencyManagement>` in your project is ignored (Is there no appropriate message in your build's output?) and thus the packaging type of the dependency`org.wso2.siddhi:siddhi-extensions:3.0.3` defaults to `jar` which doesn't exist.

But the doc, however, says:

> Imports are most effective when used for defining a "library" of related artifacts that are generally part of a multiproject build. It is fairly common for one project to use one or more artifacts from these libraries. [...] The pattern below illustrates how a "bill of materials" (BOM) can be created for use by other projects.
>
> The root of the project is the BOM pom [*`siddhi:siddhi:pom` in your case*]. It defines the versions of all the artifacts that will be created in the library. Other projects that wish to use the library should import this pom into the dependencyManagement section of their pom.
>
> [...]
>
> The parent subproject has the BOM pom as its parent. It is a normal multiproject pom. [*your `siddhi:siddhi-extensions:pom`*]

Solutions:

- Import [`org.wso2.siddhi:siddhi:3.0.3:pom`](http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/wso2/siddhi/siddhi/3.0.3/siddhi-3.0.3.pom) in your project's `<dependencyManagement>/<dependency>` or
- add the `<dependencyManagement>/<dependency>` declarations for the `siddhi-extension-...` modules you need.